# Ruby on rails database relationship structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I'm fairly new to the rails world and I've been tasked with making an online store.

However I am currently having trouble setting up the database relationships. I have **product**, **dimension** and **shipping** classes. A product can have several dimensions, depending on what product variant the customer chooses. The dimensions of the product can dictate how much the shipping will cost, however there will also be several shipping options on offer per dimensions. Here is my current setup:

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :image_url, :price, :category_id, :weighting, :stock
  has_many :dimensions
end
```

**Dimensions.rb**

```
class Weight < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product_id, :size, :weight
  has_and_belongs_to :shippings
  belongs_to :product
end
```

**Shipping.rb**

```
class Shipping < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :insurance, :name, :price, :size_id, :weight_id
  has_and_belongs_to :dimensions
end
```

Could anyone give me some advice as to whether this is the best way to setup this database relation? And if not, what would be a more optimum solution?

I've been told to utilise **has_many :through**, however I'm not sure how best to implement this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the deciding factor between `has_and_belongs_to_many` and `has_many :through` is whether you think you'll ever need the have the relation object (the one that would tie a `has_many :through` together) with attributes of its own.

For me, I rarely skimp on over-doing things like this, so I always use `has_many :through`, and if I don't add attributes to it, so be it.  It gives me a model with a useful name for the association, I can validate that association, get callbacks, etc...

The [Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) has a pretty good comparison between the two.

Also, if you're making a RoR store, have you looked at [Spree](http://spreecommerce.com)?